# Scala Argument Capture of External Class

Tags: scala, mockito

So I want to check arguments that I send to an external class that I do not control.  The external class is assumed tested, I simply want to test if I passed it the right parameters. I have tried some combination of ArgumentCaptor etc, but not much luck

```
import org.ABC.ExternalClass

case class Foo(i:Int, j: Int...) { 
  val EC = CreateExternalClass()
  def CreateExternalClass(): ExternalClass = {
   new ExternalClass (i, j, ....many parameters)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a real [mcve]. When you wrote code using captors, then **show** it and describe what didnt work. Right now you *only* dumped requirements; not showing evidence that you tried solving this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting things wrong here: you can only use an ArgumentCaptor on calls to **mocked** objects. You can't use them to "intercept" arbitrary calls between all kinds of objects.

Meaning: you could only use an ArgumentCaptor if you would be using a **mocked** ExternalClass object. But then you would not need to capture, as you probably could do simply method call argument verification.

But of course, you can't use Mockito to mock that call to `new` in your production class. The options you have:

- Turn to PowerMockito or JMockit; frameworks that allow to mock calls to new. Not recommended.
- Rework your production code to **not** do that call to new. Probably not helpful here; as this class might already be a wrapper around that external class
- Go for checking on the created object: check if you could use getter methods to simply query the newly created object to have the values that you expect to show up inside

Comment: "Meaning: you could only use an ArgumentCaptor if you would be using a mocked ExternalClass object. But then you would not need to capture, as you probably could do simply method call argument verification.".. So what is the use case for ArgumentCaptor? If I can only use it on mocked objects, but if it is mocked I can do simple method call argument verification anyways, then _when_ do I use it?  Also by simple  simply method call argument verification., you mean constructs like "when when(mock.Function(any("foo").thenReturn("bar")"?

Comment: See [here](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/11/25/mockito-argumentmatcher-vs-argumentcaptor/) for example. The point is: capturing is more complex to do, but it allows you for advanced validation steps. You can later **assert** on values you captured earlier on. But as said; it adds a lot of complexity. When I start thinking "I need to capture"; my next thought is "I should improve my production code, so I can better test it *without* the need to capture".